# Jax-RS Produce image from byte[]

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I am trying to display image when user hits url `http://localhost:8080/app/profile/getImage/5315d33284aec8c202eef15a` It should display image of id  5315d33284aec8c202eef15a.

```
My service is 



@GET
    @Path("/getImage/{id}")
    @Produces({"image/*"})
    public Response getImage(@PathParam("id") final String id)
    {
        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        try
        {

            final byte[] imageBytes = getImageBytes(id);
 System.out.println("image length "+imageBytes.length);
            builder.status(Status.OK).entity(new StreamingOutput(){
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
                {
                    output.write(imageBytes);
                    output.flush();

                }

            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println("exception "+e);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
```

But it doesn't produces image.`System.out.println("image length "+imageBytes.length);` gives output=> image length 72240 Where I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type of the image you are producing. Add `.type("image/png")` to the `ResponseBuilder` for PNG images.

```
builder.status(Status.OK).type("image/png").entity(new StreamingOutput(){
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        output.write(imageBytes);
        output.flush();
    }
});
```